# C++ Header Guards

Tags: c++

Suppose I have the following header file:

```
#ifndef TESTCLASS_H
#define TESTCLASS_H

#include <string>

class TestClass
{
public:
    TestClass();
    std::string test();
};

#endif // TESTCLASS_H
```

Do I have to put a guard around `#include <string>` as well?  If not, what if main.cpp also has `#include <string>`?

Comment: Whether necessary or not... When you create a new header file, your editor should insert the guards (defined by your local coding standard) automatically, at the top.  And everything you write goes within them, without thinking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, because the `string` header file has got its own include guards (as do the header files of all sensible libraries).

Comment: Is this "required" by the standard?

Comment: @Andre: The standard guarantees that you can say `#include <string>` to get string facilities. The manner of implementation is unspecified. A compiler could feasibly contain the standard library hard-coded and not use files at all.

Comment: @KerrekSB, Thanks, I found a reference: 17.6.2.2 in the draft standard. "A translation unit may include library headers in any order (Clause 2). Each may be included more than
once, with no effect different from being included exactly once, ..." Technically the string header can have no include guards, but the compiler should behave "as if" it has...

Answer (score 2):

Not necesarry, the c++ standard libs have their own Guards.